# How do we write validity in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
<lightning:input aura:id="inputField" 
                 type="text" value="{!v.value}" 
                 label="Enter first Name" onblur="{!c.valueChangeValidation}
                 messageWhenBadInput="You must enter a value />
```

In the Controller :

```
valueChangeValidation : function(component, event, helper) {
    var inputField = component.find('inputField');
    var value = inputField.get('v.value');
    if(value == ' ') {
        inputField.set('v.validity', {valid:false, badInput :true});
        inputField.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();

    }
}
```

In lwc with the help of template get query selector we can get the input  component. But how do I write inputCmp.set('v.validity', {valid:false , badInput:true}) in LWC??

Comment: I would think that once you have the component, you call it's `validity` setter : `input.validity = {valid:false , badInput:true};`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification) for the lightning-input element, you should be able to use the function `setCustomValidity` to set a custom error message.

```js
const dateFromInput = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input[data-id="dateFrom"]');
const isValid = this.dateFrom > this.dateTo;
dateFromInput.setCustomValidity(isValid ? "" : "Invalid date");
```

Comment: To have the field actually display the custom message you would then call dateFromInput.reportValidity();

Answer (score 0):

There are a fair number of gotchas here, so I'm sharing the solution I arrived at.  In my scenario, the value of the field is being set as a calculation from other user input fields.  Also, it was not possible to set it as a number field because the displayed value included string data (`totalHoursDisplay`).  Doubtless others will have specific scenarios like this which require custom validation.

Salient points include:

- You need to set the `validity` object for the state to change
- The `setCustomValidity()` method only sets the message, it doesn't change the field's validity state
- Since validation is firing upon submit, as well as when there is an `onchange` event on the field, the way I was able to get the validation message to show up was to execute the `focus()` and `blur()` sequence
- Validation will not show up on a `read-only` field.

My input field HTML is as follows:

```html
<lightning-input
name="totalHours"
data-field="totalHours"
value={totalHoursDisplay}
onfocus={doBlur}
label="Total Hours Entered"
variant="label-inline">
</lightning-input>

<lightning-button label="Submit" onclick={validate}></lightning-button>
```

The validation Javascript:

```js
  validate() {
    this.totalHoursValidated = this.totalHours <= maxHours;

    let totalHoursField = this.template.querySelector("[data-field='totalHours']");
    if (!totalHoursField) return;

    if (this.totalHours > this.maxHours) {
      totalHoursField.validity = { valid: false };
      totalHoursField.setCustomValidity("The sum is too high.");
      totalHoursField.focus();
      totalHoursField.blur();
    } else {
      totalHoursField.validity = { valid: false };
      totalHoursField.setCustomValidity("");
      totalHoursField.focus();
      totalHoursField.blur();
    }
  }

  // Make the field un-editable while the validation message is displayed
  doBlur(event) {
    let field = event.target.dataset.field;
    this.getField(field).blur();
  }
```